# Removing an object from std::list

Tags: c++, list

I'm wondering how can I remove an object from a C++ list - I'm trying to create a book management software and I'd like to have a function in the database (which is a list) that removes a book from it which is a passed object. I was thinking about this solution, but it won't work - seems like the == operator is not properly overloaded? Or maybe this solution is not going to work?

```
class Database
{
    list <Books> mybooks;
public:
    void BookDel(Books & temp)
    {
        mybooks.remove(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a function that can compare two `Books` to see if they are equal?

Comment: Show us `Books` code. Have you overloaded `operator==` for the same?

Comment: How to overload `operator==` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: Thank you, I looked at my overload operator and it was certainly faulty; I just corrected it and it seems to be working properly (I added the code as an answer below). One more question: what access should be set to the overload operator? Should it be public or protected or something else?

Answer (score 1):

> Or maybe this solution is not going to work?

This solution should work, as long as `Book` objects are comparable with the `operator==`.

> but it won't work - seems like the == operator is not properly overloaded?

If the operator isn't properly overloaded, then that could certainly be the problem. You should research more in depth **how** it does not work. That will give you insight about **why** it does not work, which will lead you to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My == overload was wrong, so I corrected it and it seems to be working now. This is my Books class code:

```
class Book {
    public: bool operator==(const Book & a) const
{
    bool test=false;
    if(!(this->tytul.compare(a.tytul)))
        test=true;
    return test;
}
protected:
list <Autor> authors;
string tytul;
public:
    void AddAuthor(Autor x)
{
    authors.push_back(x);
}
Books(string tytulx)
{
    tytul = tytulx;
}
};
```